# Find list of data according to reason

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have below Dataset. I need to find the list where is the ID is "created" but not "removed"

```
TimeStamp   ID  Reason
2:38:46     1   created
2:39:46     2   Created
2:40:46     1   Removed 
2:42:46     3   Created 
2:45:46     2   Updated
2:48:46     4   Created
2:45:46     3   Removed
```

Result should be for above dataset:

```
2:39:46     2   Created
2:48:46     4   Created
```

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Is `ID + Reason` unique?

Comment: Yes. ID+Reason will be unique

Answer (score 1):

`not exists` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.reason = 'Created' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.reason = 'Removed');
```